# HTML/JavaScript: How to download the file using IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have used the code below to download the from a textarea in HTML using Chrome.
I was wondering how I can get this to download when using IE (internet explorer)

```
function saveTextAsFile1()
{      
// grab the content of the form field 
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'xlsx'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "LANG_TEST.xlsx";
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "My Hidden Link";
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$filepath = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($filename));
$filesize = filesize($filepath);
$filename = substr(strrchr('/'.$filepath, '/'), 1);
$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filepath, '.'), 1));

// use this unless you want to find the mime type based on extension
$mime = array('application/octet-stream');

header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.sprintf('%d', $filesize));
header('Expires: 0');

// check for IE headers Important
if (preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false)) {
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: public');
} else {
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
}

$handle = fopen($filepath, 'rb');
fpassthru($handle);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Can that just be pluged in ??